# Limitations of Ray-casting algorithm and optional robust solution(approach) for the same?

Tags: algorithms, polygons

As per the study of point-containment algorithms and analysis of some irregular polygons, I've personally observed that in some cases this approach(Ray-casting algorithm) fail's if,

1. The ray drawn from test point crosses(intersects) once and then just “touches” one point on the outside, forming something like a “tangent”
2. The polygon is of self-intersecting type and the ray drawn from test point crosses exactly through such a crossing point
3. The ray crosses a section of a polygon where two lines of the this same polygon are drawn exactly on top of each other

   So can some one please suggest a solution or an optional approach for the point containment check that can give a more robust and optimized results?

Comment: For your 3rd example, I don't get how you would properly define the interior of such a polygon, when some of its edges overlap in that manner. For the other two, it seems the issue boils down to the ray crossing a vertex (including those formed by self-intersections). I'd think that a practical implementation of ray-casting would chose an appropriate ray that avoid vertices.

Comment: Well, just found out there is a "winding number" method to test a point in the polygon. That method basically answer both your question and the interrogation I had. Apparently, the interior as defined by the "winding number" is strictly different from the "ray casting". Intuitively, it feels like you could make them more closely related if you look at whether the winding number is even or odd. In the end, it depends what you want to call the interior of the polygon.

Comment: Thanks Alex and Bach. I found one more useful link related to same topic. http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/ray-tracing-rasterization,2351-7.html